# how can i make bootstrap menu responsive anytime?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to set my bootstrap navigation as responsive in any width that i want. For example in 1200 pixels width it should act like normal navigation but in 1110 pixels width; i want to set menu to go responsive. I tried to make it with jquery but no response. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Can you show some code? and you don't need jquery to make bootstrap responsive. it is designed to be responsive.

Comment: http://developingable.com/bootstrap-navbar/

Comment: The navbar on their own website is responsive. Just copy theirs http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: http://corpusad.com/guven/practice_area.html in this link you may check it out. I'm using cufons so in page resizing fonts make trouble. So i decided to set menu responsive mode in some screen widths but i didnt do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default Bootstrap navbar toggle threshold using a CSS media query like this..

```
@media (max-width: 1110px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/98488
(this example uses `1280`, but you can change it to `1110` to see the navbar collapse)